# How to continuously get posts mentioning a page through an app

Tags: facebook, authentication, facebook-page

I need to constantly poll for all posts that a group have people have posted mentioning a specific Facebook page. I have a user which has admin privileges to that page but is currently not friends with the group of people I need to poll. I need to do this as authenticating through my Facebook app without having people constantly enter their password. My understanding is that there is no way to do this without becoming friends with the entire group of people. Is that true?

Is it even possible to do this with becoming friends with the entire group of people (assuming that the group let's my user see their posts)? Will the group need to authenticate to my app at any point? What permissions does my app need?

Comment: Are you talking only about posts inside that specific Facebook group’s page? And how do you define “having mentioned”?

Comment: no I'm talking about posts that the group of users have just posted to their friends (or public) - like a status.

Comment: and I defined "having mentioned" as writing a post that includes @MyPageName in it

Comment: You can not get any posts from random people your user is not friends with, if their posts aren’t public.

Comment: Ok so can you do it with being friends with them as an app? That is can you have the user (who is friends with everyone I want to see) authenticate to my app or give my app permission to see their news feed ONCE. And then use my app credentials to constantly poll their news feed?

Comment: Well, if your user is their friend, then their posts should show up in your user’s stream – so it’d probably be enough to read just that.